# Show that every absolute retract space is contractible

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Show that every absolute retract space is contractible

Let $Y$ be an absolute retract space. I have the following characterization for $Y$. $$Y \text{ is an absolute retract } \iff \text{if $f$ is an embedding to a closed subset of a metrizable space $X$, then $f(Y)$ is a retract of $X.$}$$

So if I pick an embedding $f :Y \to X$, then I get a retraction $r:f(Y)\to X$ such that $r\mid_{f(Y)}=id$.

And what I need to prove is that there exists $h:Y \times [0,1] \to X$ such that for $y_0 \in Y$ I have $h(y,0)=y =id =r\mid_{f(Y)} $ and $h(y,1)=y_0$.

I would appreciate some hints on how to get further with the problem as I'm stuck here.

Comment: Did you cover absolute extensors and the Borsuk Homotopy Extension Lemma in class?

Comment: We've only covered the extension theorem of Tietze and we also have another characterization for absolute retractions namely $Y$ is an absolute retract if for metrizable $X$, $A$ closed subset of $X$ and $f:A \to Y$ we have that $g:X \to Y$ is a continuous extension of $f$.

Answer (score 21):

Let $Y$ be an AR. Let $y_0 \in Y$.

Then consider $Z=Y \times [0,1]$ with the closed subset $$A=(X\times\{0\}) \cup (\{y_0\} \times [0,1]) \cup (X \times \{1\})$$ Define $f: A \to Y$ be $f(y_0,t)=y_0$ for all $t$ and $f(y,0)=y; f(y,1)= y_0$ for all $y$. This is clearly continuous by the pasting lemma. Extend $f$ on $A$ to $H: Z \to Y$ and you've got the required homotopy using the characterisation of AR's in your comment as an absolute extensor.

Comment: This is the last contribution by Henno here in MSE. He [passed away](https://mensenlinq.nl/overlijdensberichten/henno-hendrik-sikke-brandsma-9275046/) the day he posted this answer. See also this [meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35131/about-putting-a-passed-away-notice-on-some-user-s-profiles-but-having-prior-a)

Comment: @Henno You will be remembered through your posts that will help for years to come. Rest in peace.